# Copying tables from one database to another, in Firebird 2.1

Tags: sql, database, firebird, firebird2.1

I need to copy tables from one database to another in Firebird 2.1, but in some way which is pretty quick and you can run this on console.

I used FBcopy but get the answer from boss that it is too slow. This must be done in more than one transaction because tables are quite big. Any ideas how I can do this?

Comment: Does the table already exist in the target database, does it need additional transformation? In what way is FBCopy too slow? I doubt that if FBCopy is slow, that using an alternative method will be much faster (and likely slower).

Comment: what are the data in those tables, that has to be just copied? I mean, typical data grows with time, incrementally. I have some facts year ago, half-year ago, month ago, day ago... Each day I have some new rows added. Then if we would sync two servers every week - I do not have to copy all the rows "from Adam and Eve", I only have to copy few most recent rows that were added during the last week, and prior rows were already copied before.

Comment: Destination database is created with those tables, I need just to copy there data and it doesn't need additional transformation. This idea with just copying new rows could be good. Is it possible to do this?

Comment: Everything is possible, it would just make it more complex and likely even slower.

Comment: @TheNinTri it is called "replication", usually it is said in the context of all the database, but of course it can be done on tables alone. It would be you and your coding that would decide between possible and impossible. For example, if you coded that the destination database is always deleted and started from empty space - then of course after that you have to copy all the data anew. But if you managed to keep the destination database between sessions, then you would have to calculate the difference and apply it - to insert new rows and to delete the deleted ones.

Comment: It is all about YOU analyzing YOUR large-scale task and then outlining the best FOR YOU strategy to approach it and then making YOUR implementation of that strtategy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible solution is to create [external tables](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-ddl-tbl-external) with the layout of the source table (or at least: the data you want to transfer), one in the source database and another in the target database.

In the source database, you select what you want to transfer from the source table and insert it into the (empty) external table. After that is done, you can copy the file to the other database. If they are on the same server, it is possible to use the same file directly (I haven't used external tables enough to point out risks beyond the ones pointed out below).

On the target database, you can then select from the external table and insert into the final target table.

When creating and using external tables, keep the following in mind:

- External tables files are a fixed-width **binary** data format, the documentation I link shows how you can make it look like a fixed-width text format, but it is really not.
- Correct interpretation of character data depends on the character set (both for correct character conversion and for data length), eg UTF8 columns are 4x their declared length. When creating external tables, explicitly declare the character set to avoid issues with - for example - different default character sets between databases.

  The difference between using a single byte character set vs a 4 byte character set will lead to extreme corruption, because a `CHAR(100)` in a WIN1252 database will be written/read as 100 bytes, but in a UTF8 database, it will be written/read as 400 bytes. So be sure to explicitly use a character set, eg `CHAR(100) CHARACTER SET WIN1252`.
- Given its uncompressed nature, it is better to use single bytes character sets instead of - for example - UTF8, if your data allows it.
- External tables do not support blobs or arrays.
- You cannot delete or update rows in an external table. To clear it, you need to delete the underlying external file (Firebird will automatically create a new file when necessary).
- It is not possible to define primary key or foreign key constraints, nor indexes on external tables

To be able to use external tables, you need to configure Firebird to allow it to access those files. In `firebird.conf` of the server, change the `ExternalFileAccess` setting from its default of `None` to `ExternalFileAccess = Restrict <path>`, where path is the folder or a semi-colon separated list of folders where Firebird has access. Read the documentation about this option in the config file!

A (very) small example. Assuming both database are on the same server, and your databases have a `CUSTOMER` table you want to transfer:

```
create table customer (
    id integer constraint pk_customer primary key,
    customer varchar(25) character set win1252 not null
)
```

You then create the equivalent external table:

```
create table ext_customer external file 'D:\data\DB\exttables\ext_customer.dat' (
    id integer not null,
    customer varchar(25) character set win1252 not null
)
```

Create this table in both the source database and the target database.

Then in the source database put the customer data in the external table:

```
insert into ext_customer (id, customer) select id, customer from customer;
```

Make sure to commit.

In the target database, you can then use the data. For example, if the `customer` table is currently empty, you could simply do the opposite we did in source:

```
insert into customer (id, customer) select id, customer from ext_customer;
```

If you need more control, consider looking at [`MERGE`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-dml-merge).

Comment: You should also mention that external tables does not support nulls. And he need to add another column to this ext table with information if field is null or not

Comment: @Livius Thanks, I'll double check that and update later today.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question but;

You can try to disable the indexes on the target table.
Copy data, then enable the indexes.

You can also check the triggers on the target table and disable unnecessary ones. Is there any triggers selecting from or inserting to other tables?

You can also disable "forced writes" on the target database. I assume that you have a server with redundant power supply and a raid disk system(or cloud)
After you copy, you can turn "forced writes" back on.
https://www.firebirdsql.org/pdfmanual/html/gfix-sync.html